# Sharing Google Calendar's in an Organization

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

**Question:**
*Is there a simple way to automatically share a calendar with users in a Google Organization.*

**Current Technology:**
I am looking in to streamlining our calendars within our organization. We are using a Google business account for our calendars, emails, contacts, and we sync it all on to our Mac's.

**Current Method:**
When we add a new calendar for each office location, (1) we have to create calendar on the super admin account, (2) share it with everyone, (3) each user must accept the calendar, (4) then we use google Sync Select to add the calendar to their list, and (5) finally we sync it with iCal.

**Issues with Current Method:**
- Too many steps for a large group of users
- Cluttered calendars (since we all share a calendar based off office location)
- Difficult to assign specific events

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 0):

Steps 1-3 can be done automatically through Google Calendar APIv3. You can create a service account, delegate the domain authority to it and then use it to create the new calendars and share them. Take a look into authority delegation here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

The documentation for API v3 is here: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/